# Iterate Over a List of Strings by Character in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
Phone Number = "3662277815781519518916891"
Words = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "emo", "cap", "car", "cat"]
foo -> 366
```

So in this problem I'm given a phone number as a string, and a list of words. Each letter corresponds to a number just as it would appear on a phone's dial screen. (ex: 2 -> abc, 3 -> def, etc...) Basically I need to find if each word exists in our given phone number. So my logic is to use a dictionary with the letters and their paired digit on a phone's dial screen as my key value pairs respectively. Then I want to convert each word in our words list to its digit representative. So for example, foo -> 366. And then finally I want to do a simple check to see if each word is in our phone number string; if it is return true, if not return false. I think my logic is fairly straightforward, but my implementation seems entirely wrong.

So in my code I am trying to traverse each letter of each word in our list, and then convert that letter to its value pair in our dictionary. What is the best way of doing this?

```
def phone(num, words):

    conversions = {"abc": 2, "def": 3, "ghi": 4, "jkl": 5, "mno": 6, "pqrs": 7, "tuv": 8, "wxyz": 9}

    for word in words:
        for letter in word:
            conversions.get(letter)
            #letter += 1
    print (words)
```

EDIT: num is the phone number string we are given and words is the list of words they give us (also represented as strings)

Comment: what you pass to the argument words in function `phone (num, words)`?

Comment: Just edited the post to reflect, but num is our phone number string, and words is a list of words given to us that are represented as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple.  The dictionary should take a single letter and convert it to a digit.

{'a':'2', 'b':'2', 'c':'2', 'd':'3', ...}

Comment: I thought I may need to do that, is that the best way to implement this?

Comment: It's the best way I know.  Sometimes people come up with better solutions than I ever imagined.  

Of course, this is only a part of the solution, which you've probably finished by now.